# Wordpress Contact Form 7 dynamically select dropdown field based on url

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following case. I have Contact Form 7 plugin and couple of pages with different services. Each page has a contact form with select dropdown in the sidebar with all services.
How can I achieve that when you are in a specific service, the dropdown field is selected automatically by default based on the service (probably by URL)?
I do not find such topics and I am very interested in how this happens. Preferably without a plugin. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have 3 services, Service A, Service B, Service C, such that if you are in a page that belongs to service B, with URL `domain.com/service-b/my-page`, in other words, the URL itself has enough information to identify that this page is part of Service B.  There are 2 ways to proceed to achieve the automatic selection in your dropdown,

1  on the client-side, using JavaScript once the page has loaded,

use the following script to select the right option,

```js
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
  //determine the current page,
  let page = window.location.href, opt='';
  //comment the following line for your site, this is only for this example test.
  page = 'http://example.com/service-b/my-page';

  switch(true){
    case page.indexOf('service-b')>0:
      opt='serviceb';
      break;
    case page.indexOf('service-c')>0:
      opt='servicec';
      break;
    case page.indexOf('service-a')>0:
      opt='servicea';
      break;
  }

  $('select[name="select-services"]').find('option[value="'+opt+'"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
})
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-services">
 <option value="">select a service</option>
 <option value="servicea">Service A</option>
 <option value="serviceb">Service B</option>
 <option value="servicec">Service C</option>
</select>
```

2 the other way is modify the select option on the server side prior to page load using php and hooking the filter 'do_shortcode_tag' which is fired once the cf7 form shortcode has been executed.  Place the following code in your themes `functions.php` file,

```
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag','set_service',10,3);
function set_service($html, $attr, $tag){
  //check this is a cf7 shortcode.
  if('contact-form-7' !== $tag){
    return $output;
  }
  //if you have several forms, you can also check this is the right form using $attr['id']
  //determine which page you are on
  global $wp;
  $serv='';
  switch(true){
    case false !== strpos($wp->request, 'service-a' ):
      $serv='servicea';
      break;
      case false !== strpos($wp->request, 'service-b' ):
      $serv='serviceb';
      break;
    case false !== strpos($wp->request, 'service-c' ):
      $serv='servicec';
      break;
  }
  return str_replace('value="'.$serv.'"', 'value="'.$serv.'" selected="selected"', $html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately, I can't handle both. The JavaScript solution gives me a syntax error around .find - 'missing) after argument list' and the php solution my whole contact form disappears. Obviously I'm not doing something right. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I made a type in the js code, I have corrected it and set it up as a jsfiddle example, you can run the test and see it work.    The above is either/or solution, either 1 on the client-side using JavaScript, or solution 2 on the server side using PHP, you don't require both.

Comment: Yes, of course, I just couldn't adjust either. Now everything works perfectly with the javascript solution. Thank you very much for the quick and correct answers :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Sorry :( Soon i'll have 15 :)

Comment: True, but you can choose the answer ...unless you're hoping to get another one.

Comment: Oh sorry. I did it :) Thanks again

Comment: Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

***You can try by wp filter hook :***

```
add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag','sercice_check',10,3);

function sercice_check($output, $tag, $attr){

// Checking your contact form id
// [contact-form-7 id="659" title="My Service"]

  if(  isset( $attr['id'] ) &&  $attr['id'] == 659 ){ //you can even check for specific attributes
    global $wp;

    $service='';

    // Site url like : www.mysite.com/service/service-a/
    switch(true){

        case false !== strpos($wp->request, 'service-a' ):
            $service='Service A';
        break;

        case false !== strpos($wp->request, 'service-a' ):
            $service='Service B';
        break;
    }

    return str_replace('value="'.$service.'"', 'value="'.$service.'" selected="selected"', $output);
  }

  return $output;
}
```