# Wordpress Contact Form 7 dynamically autoselect dropdown field based on referral url

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have been working off of these two answers:

[Wordpress Contact Form 7 dynamically select dropdown field based on url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251548/wordpress-contact-form-7-dynamically-select-dropdown-field-based-on-url)

[Auto-select fields in Contact form 7 based on referral link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294827/auto-select-fields-in-contact-form-7-based-on-referral-link)

Currently, the code below is pasted in the CSS block on the /contact page:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {

  //determine the previous page,
  let page = document.referrer, opt='';


  switch(true){
    case page.indexOf(’douglas-h-flint’)>0:
      opt=‘douglashflint’;
      break;
    case page.indexOf(‘john-f-connolly’)>0:
      opt=‘johnfconnolly’;
      break;
    case page.indexOf(‘david-l-walker-jr’)>0:
      opt=‘davidlwalkerjr’;
      break;
  }

  $('select[name=“select-recipient”]’).find('option[value="'+opt+'"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
})
})(jQuery);

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select-recipient”>
 <option value="">General Inquiry</option>
 <option value=“douglashflint”>Douglas H. Flint</option>
 <option value=“johnfconnolly”>John F. Connolly</option>
 <option value=“davidlwalkerjr”>David L. Walker, Jr.</option>
</select>
```

My website is: https://c7n.f22.myftpupload.com/

My goal is that when someone navigates to the /contact page *directly* from one of these people's individual pages—(/attorneys/douglas-h-flint) or (/attorneys/john-f-connolly) or (/attorneys/david-l-walker-jr)—that the "Inquire with:" dropdown field in the contact form would autoselect their respective name and that when someone navigates to the /contact page from any other page on the site, the "Inquire with:" dropdown field would remain defaulted to "General Inquiry" option.

What am I missing? Or what am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answer is a good answer, it's not quite WordPress useable as is.  Since this is contact form 7, and WordPress, there are a few things wrong with it.

1. Don't re-add jQuery this way `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` the jQuery library is already included with WordPress.
2. jQuery is loaded in `no conflict` mode, so you have to initialize first with `jQuery` and not `$`
3. You can add your script to your contact form 7 form like this [image: contact form example] although this is not the absolute best way to do it. It will work without adding a bunch of javascript to another file.  There are also easy ways to use `wp_add_inline_script` to properly enqueue your script conditionally.

So if you add the following to your contact form... it will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  //determine the previous page,
  let page = document.referrer, opt = '';
  switch(true){
    case page.indexOf('douglas-h-flint') > -1:
      opt = 'douglashflint';
      break;
    case page.indexOf('john-f-connolly') > -1:
      opt = 'johnfconnolly';
      break;
    case page.indexOf('david-l-walker-jr') > -1:
      opt = 'davidlwalkerjr';
      break;
  }
  $('select[name="select-recipient"]').find('option[value="'+opt+'"]').prop('selected', true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Howard E! This helped me fill in the gaps to get the rest of the way there. Your solution worked perfectly, except I swapped out the opt = "douglashflint" values for the way I actually had them listed in the dropdown of my CF7. Grateful for the expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the funny stylish quotes (`‘`, `’`, `“` and `”`) that you have. Those will break JS. Remove them from the HTML markup and CSS as well.

Beyond that, the expected value for the second argument of the `.prop()` method is a boolean (`true` or `false`), so that would be:

```
$('select[name="select-recipient"]').find('option[value="'+opt+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Finally, it is quite scary to read *the code below is pasted in the CSS block...* Place this code inside the `<head>` tag of the page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  //determine the previous page,
  let page = document.referrer, opt = '';

  switch(true){
    case page.indexOf('douglas-h-flint') > -1:
      opt = 'douglashflint';
      break;
    case page.indexOf('john-f-connolly') > -1:
      opt = 'johnfconnolly';
      break;
    case page.indexOf('david-l-walker-jr') > -1:
      opt = 'davidlwalkerjr';
      break;
  }

  $('select[name="select-recipient"]').find('option[value="'+opt+'"]').prop('selected', true);
})
</script>
```